Intel Realsense d455 in Ros 1
Intel real sense d455 is not working with ROS1 (Hardware Jetson Orin Nano)
While the Intel RealSense camera D455 is functioning correctly in the Intel RealSense viewer on the Jetson Orin Nano with ROS1 Noetic distribution on Ubuntu 20, the point cloud visualization through ROS1 with "roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch filters:=pointcloud" does not detect the camera.
Despite successfully operating with the Intel RealSense viewer on the Jetson Orin Nano, the Intel RealSense camera D455 fails to be recognized in ROS1 with the Noetic distribution on Ubuntu 20 when attempting point cloud visualization via "roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch filters:=pointcloud," even after following these steps:

Installed ros-noetic-rgbd-launch via "sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rgbd-launch."
Launched the RealSense camera with "roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_rgbd.launch."


Have you tried using realsense's official app to visualize it first? from the error i could see that it's because the connection between your pc and realsense
